# Why does my sago palm have yellow spots?

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, leaves, pest-control, pest-damage

[image]
My Sago palm has suddenly developed a lot of yellowish spots on all the leaves, topside only.
I found no pests on it at least that i could see. What can it be?

Comment: Can you add a  photo and a bit more detail please - what part of the world are you in? Is the plant in a pot indoors our outside. If outside, is it in the ground? And how long have you had the plant?

Comment: Hello, I'm in Portugal and the sago plant is outside in the ground. I planted it 3 years ago

Answer (score 1):

I have about 10 Segos in E. TX,I just looked and found mine have similar spots. But mine have fewer,from 50% to only 10% of the numbers of spots yours has. I see no pests. No answer; but a crazy guess- We had a hail storm about 6 weeks ago , my three largest segos are protected under trees and have the least spots ( less than 10% yours). Have you had hail ?

Comment: Yes, I had a big thunderstorm with hail, and in fact I only noticed the spots after that. The more protected leaves are fine, like the new ones. Is it possible that it damage from the hail as you say?

Comment: Either hail or surprising coincidence.